# Better looping, for string manipulation (python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

If i have this code

```
s = 'abcdefghi'
for grp in (s[:3],s[3:6],s[6:]):
    print "'%s'"%(grp)

    total = calc_total(grp)

    if (grp==s[:3]):
        # more code than this
        p = total + random_value
        x1 = my_function(p)

    if (grp==s[3:6]):
        # more code than this
        p = total + x1
        x2 = my_function(p)

    if (grp==s[6:]):
        # more code than this
        p = total + x2
        x3 = my_function(p)
```

If the group is the first group, perform code for this group, if the group is the second group, perform code using the a value generated from code performed for the first group, the same applies for the third group, using a generated value from code for the second group:

How can i tidy this up to use better looping?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd code something like this as follows:

```
for i, grp in enumerate((s[:3],s[3:6],s[6:])):
    print "'%s'"%(grp)

    total = calc_total(grp)
    # more code that needs to happen every time

    if i == 0:
        # code that needs to happen only the first time
    elif i == 1:
        # code that needs to happen only the second time
```

etc.  The `==` checks can be misleading if one of the groups "just happens" to be the same as another one, while the `enumerate` approach runs no such risk.

Answer (score 3):

I may have misunderstood what you're doing, but it appears that you want to do something to s[:3] on the first iteration, something different to s[3:6] on the second, and something else again to s[6:] on the third. In other words, that isn't a loop at all! Just write those three blocks of code out one after another, with s[:3] and so on in place of grp.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include my `total = calc_total(grp)` statement

Answer (score 1):

I must say I agree with Peter in that the loop is redundant. If you are afraid of duplicating code, then just move the repeating code into a function and call it multiple times:

```
s = 'abcdefghi'

def foo(grp):
    # Anything more you would like to happen over and over again
    print "'%s'"%(grp)
    return calc_total(grp)

def bar(grp, value):
    total = foo(grp)
    # more code than this
    return my_function(total + value)

x1 = bar(s[:3], random_value)
x2 = bar(s[3:6], x1)
x3 = bar(s[6:], x2)
```

If

```
    # more code than this
```

contains non-duplicate code, then you must of course move that out of "bar" (which together with "foo" should be given a more descriptive name).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = reduce(lambda x, grp: my_function(calc_total(list(grp)) + x),
        map(None, *[iter(s)] * 3), random_value)
```

At the end, you'll have the last `x`.

Or, if you want to keep the intermediary results around,

```
x = []
for grp in map(None, *[iter(s)] * 3):
    x.append(my_function(calc_total(list(grp)) + (x or [random_value])[-1]))
```

Then you have `x[0]`, `x[1]`, `x[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Get your data into the list you want, then try the following:

```
output = 0
seed = get_random_number()
for group in input_list:
    total = get_total(group)
    p = total + seed
    seed = my_function(p)
```

`input_list` will need to look like `['abc', 'def', 'ghi']`.  But if you want to extend it to `['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr']`, this should still work.